# Retag Request: [queuing-theory] --> [queueing-theory]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I'm proposing a retag as: `[queuing-theory]` --> `[queueing-theory]`. You can vote for it here:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags/queueing-theory/synonyms

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory#Overview):

> The spelling "queueing" over "queuing" is typically encountered in the academic research field. In fact, one of the flagship journals of the profession is named [Queueing Systems](http://www.springerlink.com/content/101752/).

Please comment and vote as you see apt.

Comment: Note that one has to have enough (5 scores) upvoted answers in that specific tag to upvote the proposal.

Comment: Google gives 11M hits for queuing, and 10M for queueing, 190K for "queuing theory" and 267K for "queueing theory". I would think either spelling is acceptable. But you really should make one of the spellings a synonym of the other.

Comment: @Peter: Grammatically, `queuing` is the correct form, since the final `e` is dropped when the word takes `-ing` (except in special cases). That's why there are more results for `queuing` than there are for `queueing`. However, `queueing theory` is a **stylized** term for this field in academia, and so I think we should respect it. Anyway, your last sentence tells everything: "[we] should make one of the spellings a synonym of the other."

Comment: @Sadeq: And given the wikipedia quote, I agree that "queueing" is the obvious choice. (Unless we have any vocal grammar sticklers here.)

Comment: @Peter we can send them off to english.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: I'm not sure there are even enough people with 5 upvoted answers in queueing theory to carry this proposal. Can moderators make this change?

Comment: @Peter: Good call!

Comment: Rereading my comment, I see I misspoke. I meant 5 upvotes on answers in queueing theory. But still ... Are any moderators listening?

Comment: I am now :). (we really need more moderators). It's done.

Comment: @Sadeq: Both forms are correct in non-academic English.  (And that should be "orthographically", not "grammatically".)  See also "cueing" vs "cuing".

Comment: @JeffE: Thanks for pointing out the difference between "orthographically" and "grammatically." Several spell-checkers catch "queueing" as error, and that's why I said it's incorrect. However, few dictionaries (such as Concise Oxford English or Merriam-Webster) cite both spelling. (Maybe due to its academic use?) Anyway, I'm not a lexicographer, and as Suresh suggested, such discussion is apt for english.stackexchange.com.